# How to run mvc application on mac os

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

I have a ASP.net mvc application and run it on windows without any error but when I copy this application and run it on mac os with visual studio for mac, I get error 500 in web server.
There isn't any error at build time and the error raise on run time.
My application works with framework 4.6.

Comment: What is the actual error that is thrown?

Comment: @mahlatse , I get error 500

Comment: In your Global.asx file, when you check the Application_Errors method, what error does it give you?

Comment: @alirezakhosravi please reply to feedback, otherwise you may get downvotes